# Create UTM NetCDF to be opened in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, netcdf, utm

I successfully created a NetCDF file in C++ and opened it in ArcGIS Pro using a coordinate system with longitude and latitude, the resulting .nc file looks like this:

```
dimensions:
    longitude = 601 ;
    latitude = 341 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (17 currently)
variables:
    double longitude(longitude) ;
        longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
        longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
    double latitude(latitude) ;
        latitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
        latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
    int time(time) ;
        time:units = "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:0.0" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
    float data(time, latitude, longitude) ;
//////////////data////////////
```

Now I wanted to create the same NetCDF file in UTM coordinate system but I can't seem to figure out how to put the values in the .nc file, I tried to simply put the UTM coordinates inside the latitude and longitude variables and setting both of them with the attributes found on [this](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/v4.5/reference/StandardCoordinateTransforms.html) page but ArcGIS doesn't seem to detect the coordinates correctly.

Are UTM coordinates inside .nc files supported by ArcGIS? if so, can someone provide an example of how the .nc file is supposed to look (I can recreate the structure in my C++ program once I figure out how it's supposed to look and it's parameters)?

Comment: Did you add an `grid_mapping` attribute to `data()` that pointed to the a crs with the proper UTM data per  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/voxel-layer-freqently-asked-questions.htm#anchor3 and  http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#grid-mappings-and-projections

Comment: @DaveX so i should call `double longitude` and `double latitude` as `double projection_y_coordinate` and `double projection_x_coordinate` respectively, add a `data:grid_mapping = crs` and a `char crs` with attributes `crs:grid_mapping = universal_transverse_mercator`, `crs:utm_zone_number = 3` and so on right?

Comment: I don't know arcGIS well, but other netCDF software cares about the `standard_name` attributes over the variable's names . Per the https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/voxel-layer-freqently-asked-questions.htm#anchor3 it looks like it counts on a global attribute of `esri_pe_string` with a WKT.   You can also try a WKT into the `crs:crs_wkt` attributes too per http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#british-national-grid-newlyn-datum-in-crs-wkt-format -- it has a rich example that ArcGIS could possibly make sense of.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks much for this post.  It took some figuring, but lead me to my answer.

In python I did the following to get UTM zone 10N recognized in Arc Pro 2.8.3.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
from osgeo import osr

fn = 'C:/temp/test.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(fn, 'w', format='NETCDF4')

###############################################################################

timeVar = ds.createDimension(dimname='time', size=None)
x = ds.createDimension('x', 10)
y = ds.createDimension('y', 10)

###############################################################################

timeVar = ds.createVariable('time', 'f4', ('time',))
timeVar.long_name = 'time'
timeVar.axes = 'T'
timeVar.units = 'hours since 1900-01-01 00:00' 
timeVar.calendar = 'gregorian'

x = ds.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x',))
x.units = "m"
x.long_name = 'Easting'
x.standard_name = 'projection_x_coordinate'
x.axis = "X"

y = ds.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y',))
y.units = "m"
y.long_name = 'Northing'
y.standard_name = 'projection_y_coordinate'
y.axis = "Y"

value = ds.createVariable('value', 'f4', ('time', 'y', 'x',))
value.units = 'Unknown'

#######################
# add data for Arc Pro Projection

proj = osr.SpatialReference()
proj.ImportFromEPSG(26910) # NAD83 UTM 10N

# this is the magic right here!
value.esri_pe_string = proj.ExportToWkt()

#######################
# write data 

timeVar[:] = np.array([0,1])

x[:] = np.arange(543550, 553550, 1000)
y[:] = np.arange(4173500, 4183500, 1000)

print('var size before adding data', value.shape)

value[0, :, :] = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(10, 10))

print('var size after adding first data', value.shape)
xval = np.linspace(0.5, 5.0, 10)
yval = np.linspace(0.5, 5.0, 10)
value[1, :, :] = np.array(xval.reshape(-1, 1) + yval)

print('var size after adding second data', value.shape)

ds.close()
```

Comment: Could you share an example of the NetCDF file you produced using this script? I'm using a different software to produce a compatible NetCDF, and it would be very helpful to have an example of a UTM-based grid that works. The original poster also asked for this.

Comment: @Nena - I have uploaded an example netcdf to the link below.  Cheers! [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16fY8YjisIiA9QXwar4RMYph92zHUboQ9/view?usp=sharing)